# Distinct MySQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hoping someone can help me with a MYSQL query

I have 3 database tables:

- points_of_interest
- point_of_interest_type
- poi_poi_types

The `points_of_interest` table contains all details about an area.

The `point_of_interest_type` table is a list of types e.g Restaurant, Cafe, Museum etc. This table also has an active column (1 or 0)

The `poi_poi_types` is a mapping table - so it contains the id of the point of interest and the id of the point of interest type

A Point of Interest can have many Point of Interest types so potentially can have multiple entries in the poi_poi_types table

So the results I want are to return a list of points_of_interest but only for active point of interest types

This is the codeignitor query I have so far but its not correct - it is returning every instant of the actual point of interest that is in the poi_poi_types table

```
    $this->db->select('poi.*, poi_types.type as poi_type');
    $this->db->from('poi');
    $this->db->join('poi_poi_types', 'poi.id = poi_poi_types.poi_id');
    $this->db->join('poi_types', 'poi_types.id = poi_poi_types.poi_type_id');
    $this->db->where('poi_types.active', 1);
```

Comment: So you want to group your result by the actual point of interest, generating the `poi.*` information only once and the `poi_types` information for each active type (in a list)?

Comment: Yes correct - that is exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @user1801579, did you try the answer I posted?

Comment: Yes I tried it .. It is not 100% correct and still doesn't produce a distinct result for a POI ... If a POI has two entries in the poi_poi_types table then two results are been produced ... I only want one

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. Well, for setting it to make the select statement distinct.  I think this would essentially do `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('poi.*, poi_types.type as poi_type');
$this->db->from('poi');
$this->db->join('poi_poi_types', 'poi.id = poi_poi_types.poi_id');
$this->db->join('poi_types', 'poi_types.id = poi_poi_types.poi_type_id');
$this->db->where('poi_types.active', 1);
```